# Como puedo hacer que la grafica muestre datos de una tabla, pero solo los del usuario que esta logueado

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo la tabla de usuarios y una tabla pivot de nomina_user donde guardo la fechas de inicio y final de quincena y el usuario de quien es la nomina, y esas tablas las conecto con otra que se llama serins la cual guarda los servicios realizados en esa nomina de ese usuario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cada que se registra un usuario se le da un tipo para asignarle un rol y según su rol entre a su vista, en este caso la grafica se tiene que llenar según los servicios que a realizado el técnico, pero al momento de entrar a la vista de la grafica se trae todos los registros de la tabla serins y lo que necesito es que solo traiga los del usuario que se esta logueando.

esta es la función que uso en mi controlador para traer los datos.

```
public function index()
{

$users=serins::select (DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
    ->whereYear('fecha', date('Y'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("Month(fecha)"))
    ->pluck('count');

$months=serins::select (DB::raw("Month(fecha) as month"))
        ->whereYear('fecha', date('Y'))
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("Month(fecha)"))
        ->pluck('month');



$datas= array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    foreach ($months as $index => $month){
        $datas[$month] = $users[$index];
    }



return view('tecnico_instalador', compact('datas'));
    }
```

Y esta es la vista donde se muestra.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="">
        <title>Grafico</title>
    </HEAD>

    <body>
        <div id="chart-container"></div>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

        <script>
            var datas = <?php echo json_encode($datas)?>

            Highcharts.chart('chart-container',{
                title: {
                    text: 'Incremento de productividad'
                },
                subtitle:{
                    text: 'Fuente: Servicios Realizados'
                },
                xAxis:{
                    categories: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mzo', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agt', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
                },
                yAxis:{
                    title:{
                        text: 'Numero servicios realizados'
                    }
                },
                legend:{
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series:{
                        allowPointSelect: true
                    }
                },
                series:[{
                    name: 'Servicios',
                    data: datas
                }],
                responsive: {
                    rules:[{
                        condition:{
                            maxwidth:500
                        },
                        chartOptions:{
                            legend:{
                                layout: 'horizontal',
                                align: 'center',
                                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Lo que necesitas es filtrar sólo los registros del [usuario logueado](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user). Por lo que debes agregar un `where('user_id', Auth::id())` a tus consultas. Por lo que veo, tu tabla no tiene dicha columna, puedes optar por agregársela o hacer un join con nomina_user.

Comment: No tengo el campo user_id en la tabla serins, ya que eso se relaciona en la tabla nomina_user. Cómo podría utilizar el join??

Comment: Algo [así](https://pastebin.com/ESXb6699)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda ya funciona.